# realtime data updation in cakephp or php

Tags: ajax, json, node.js, cakephp, jsonp

i am working on a Cakephp 2.x .

I have a loader/spinner on my view page which is waiting for a response from user's mobile device. Unfortunately i'm compeletly blank on how to get the request from mobile device, and update the page content real time.

here is the function

```
 <script>
var cancelled = true;

 $.modal.prompt('Enter message :', function(value)
{
  $.ajax({
  type:"POST",
  data:{value:value},
  url:"/cakephp/api/getData/",
  success : function(data) {
     //i am starting the spinner here .. 
   here i want to get the value from an android device ..as soon as i receive the value i want to stop the spinner
},
   error : function() {
   alert("error");
 }
    });
    }, function()
      {
   });
     };
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in three ways:

1- Using `webSocket` it's really real time, you should create a webSocket connection through client with `javascript` and server with any `webSocket` server such as `node.js` or `ratchet`. disadvantage of `webSocket` is some old browsers doesn't support it.

2- using `Long polling`,it creates connection to server like `AJAX` does, but `keep-alive` connection open for some time (not long though), during connection open client can receive data from server. Client have to reconnect periodically after connection is closed due to timeouts. On server side it still treated like `HTTP` request same as `AJAX`. in client side you can use a `javascript` library like `strophe` and on server side can `ejabberd` for long pulling server.

3- using `AJAX` in intervals ,you can send a request in intervals to check if any response recieved from user's mobile device in server or not.  but it is not really real time.

Comment: what about jsonp ? is that possible in jsonp?

Comment: it depend on you. If your users use modern browser the best approach is websocket, if not long pulling is better, but long pulling is a bit complex than ajax.
JSONP is a communication technique used in JavaScript programs which run in Web browsers. it mostly use for web services, I think it's irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: well i have never worked on websockets .and i dont even know the thing about it .. thankyou for your answer .. so you are saying that these three only are the solution ov my problem

Comment: your problem is very unclear, if you describe your solution in more detail, So I can provide you a solution in more detail.

Comment: sir actually the problem is i am sending some data to my controller function  through ajax.. as soon as the data goes into the controller ..i am starting the spinner ... and now in controller function i am sending some parameters to the online api which is giving me some result if api successfully execute .. remember the api ...the api send some data to the android device///... now i want to send some parameter from android to my webapp so i can stop the spinner ..

Comment: .because the api returns only the api result .. and i cant stop the spinner basis on the api result ... i want to notify my webapp that android function execute successfully now stop the spinner